# Remove ads after ad click - ADMOB

Tags: android, admob

I have few free applications for Android in play store. I want to make it clear if its against the admob rules to make ads disappear, for example 12 hours after user click on an advertisement. Admob term of service says:

> Encouraging clicks
>
> Publishers may not ask others to click their ads or use deceptive implementation methods to obtain clicks. This includes, but is not limited to, offering compensation to users for viewing ads or performing searches, promising to raise money for third parties for such behavior or placing images next to individual ads.

I am not sure if this includes what I want to do, I know a lot of experienced publishers here so ideas are welcome.

Comment: So if a user click on an Ad it disappears for 12 hours? And if that is what you want, you will somehow convey to the user to that effect?

Comment: Exactly. There will be a CheckBoxPreference in settings that enable or disable this behaviour.

Comment: Then I think that would be a violation of the term you have already mentioned. It is as good as asking users to click and hence a violation. A better alternative would be creating a paid version without Ads and promoting that instead. If you are in a country that can post paid apps that is.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I am not in such country. Anyways, as I thought.. Thanks for your comment.